# Scrolling the Output Produces Highlighting of Various Syntax. Why?

Tags: texstudio, syntax-highlighting

I am using TexStudio 2.6.6

When I scroll the syntax, there is no yellow highlighting that occurs.

However, when I scroll through the output, various paragraphs, as well as certain commands such as \newpage and \begin{center} consistently become highlighted. And, as I continue scrolling, I must bear with unwanted ``blocks of yellow'' that seem to extend throughout the syntax of the whole document.

I do not know what causes this, and would like it to cease.

I have gone to *Configure TexStudio* and then to both *Syntax Highlighting* and *Custom Highlighting* but I still cannot see how to prevent the seemingly arbitrary highlighting of certain paragraphs and various commands.

Does anyone know how to prevent this highlighting that occurs when I choose to click on and scroll through the output?

Comment: I added the texstudio tag as question is not about latex per se

Comment: Your version of TexStudio is roughly seven years old, have you tried upgrading to version 3?